# C# DataGridView - What is this column with a bullet point in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having a bit of trouble working out what the first column is on my DataGridView. It's the one that has the bulletpoint in it. I have data being loaded into column 1 - column 3. Just looking at how I can resize the column with the bullet point in it.

[image]

Here's is the collection also.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the RowHeader.  Look the properties in your DataGridView (maybe sort alphabetically) and look and all properties starting RowHeaders for an idea of what you can set.

To change the width, set the RowHeadersWidth property.

Also that's not a bulletpoint, it's an asterisk and shows you are adding a new row.  If you don't want to be able to add rows, set the AllowUserToAddRows to False.  Or in designer, click arrow top right of your DataGridView and select from there

Comment: You can also turn off showing the row- and columnheaders.